# Extra space on the top and left of a video in <iframe></iframe> in xcode Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, iframe, youtube, uiwebview

Hey guys so I'm a bit confused as to why every video I try to embed has a white/blank border on the top and left sides of the iframe. My goal is to have the video fill up the width of the screen. Take a look at my code and screenshots and see if you know the problem. I feel I have missed something simple. Any help is appreciated.

```
func getVideo(videoID:String, viewID:UIWebView) {
    let videoCode = videoID
    let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
    let view = viewID


    view.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    view.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
    view.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"375\" height=\"211\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)\(videoCode)?&playsInLine=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    getVideo(videoID:"h8SklPi-mms", viewID:videoView)
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

[main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4mRt.png)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaVti.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and thought I would share for anyone having the same or similar issue.

```
let htmlStyle = "<style> iframe { margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; } html, body { margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; width: 100%; height: 100%; } </style>"
//Seems to be all the stuff that removes space etc.


viewSelector!.loadHTMLString("<html><head><style>\(htmlStyle)</style></head><body><iframe width='\(viewSelector!.frame.width)' height='\(viewSelector!.frame.height)' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)?&playsinline=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

viewSelector is the variable used to identify which UIWebView this is being used on.

videoCode is the code imported by a text field to determine which video is being played.

Hope I could help!